# How to ensure data passes to view has specifics keys in laravel with phpunit testing

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, tdd

if my data that passes to view has structure like this:

```
[
  'foo' => [
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
  ],
  'bar' => [
    'c' => 3,
    'd' => 4,
  ],
]
```

how can I write a test for this, that assert this array should have foo,a,b,bar... keys?

it likely checks the structure of array, but since assertjsonstructure() method exist only for json response I can not use this method for this issue.

to make it easy understand what I need here my code:

```
public function show($slug): View
{
  $post = Post::whereStatus('RELEASED')
              ->whereSlug($slug)
              ->firstOrFail();

  $permissions['access_to_edit'] = FALSE;
  $permissions['access_to_delete'] = FALSE;

  return view('post.news.show',compact('post','permissions'));
}
```

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function news_can_be_shown()
{
  $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

  $post = PostFactory::released()->withImage()->create();

  $response = $this->get(route('news.show',['slug' => $post->slug]))
                   ->assertOk()
                   ->getOriginalContent()
                   ->getData();

  // I need something like this:
  $response->assertArrayStruct([
    'post' => [
      'id','main_title','secondary_title',...
    ],
    'permissions' => [
      'access_to_edit','access_to_delete'
    ]
  ]);


  // But so far I have not been able to write anything better than this:
  $this->assertEquals($news->id,$response['post']['id']);
  $this->assertEquals($news->main_title,$response['post']['main_title']);
  $this->assertEquals($news->secondary_title,$response['post']['secondary_title']);
  $this->assertEquals($news->context,$response['post']['context']);
  $this->assertEquals($news->slug,$response['post']['slug']);
  $this->assertEquals($news->user->name,$response['post']['user']['name']);
  $this->assertEquals($news->image->path,$response['post']['image']['path']);
  $this->assertEquals($news->comment,$response['post']['comment']);
  $this->assertEquals($news->like,$response['post']['like']);
  $this->assertEquals($news->dislike,$response['post']['dislike']);
  $this->assertEquals($news->view,$response['post']['view']);
  $this->assertEquals($news->created_at,$response['post']['created_at']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your test is not far away from what you want, but I am going to show you the right way for this.

First of all, some tips:

- Do not use `route('name')` because you are testing that the desired route exists, so if you write `asdasdsd` as your `news.show`, here in the test it will pass, but it will not when you go to the desired URL, so hardcode your URL in the test and never use `route` helper.
- Remember to remove `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();`, never leave it in a test, only use it for testing errors (and fixing them)
- No need to do `->getOriginalContent()....` as there are methods for testing anything you want from the response, so write in your mind to never use `getOriginalContent` again (you will see with my code).

Now, your test should be like this:

```php
/**
 * @test
 */
public function news_can_be_shown()
{
    $post = PostFactory::released()->withImage()->create();

    $response = $this->get("/your/route/{$post->slug}");

    $response->assertOk();

    $response->assertViewHas('post', $post);

    $response->assertViewHas(
        'permissions',
        function (array $permissions) {
            return $permissions['access_to_edit'] === false &&
                $permissions['access_to_delete'] === false;
        }
    );
}
```

If you want more precision, you can modify any of those 2 functions and do any check, the only condition is that the function must return `true` (if it has what you want) or `false` (did not pass assertion).

More info about [`assertViewHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-view-has) and also see the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/40104bac79e74aeea5b2b5479de3d9430198899a/src/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.php#L831-L857) as the documentation is not showing what I did, but if you see the source code, it can accept what I passed as the second argument.

---

If you want to know more or add any more tests, edit your question and I will gladly edit my answer too.

Comment: Hey. thank you for your helping. I found the answer with your hint, but not exactly you mentioned. I actually use assertViewHasAll() method that I never knew this exist. this method get any key I want should exist in data response. and surprisingly this get dot character for deep into multi level array. so with all I said my code changed to this: ``` $this->get(route('news.show',['slug' => $news->slug]))->assertOk()->assertViewHasAll([ 'post', 'post.id', 'post.main_title', 'post.secondary_title', . . . ``` – alirezadp10 just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: Awesome then ! Just see the source code if you want to know more about that method.